# Get Multiple Taxonomy by Name

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want to get certain taxonomies by name to filter a post type by type:

```
$taxonomies = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => array('post_tag','case_study','area'),
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

But when I tried to var_dump this data it shows an error invalid taxonomy.

Did I had the wrong code? I can't see it on the documentation also.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the logical relationship between each inner taxonomy array when there is more than one.

The relation key in the array describes the relationship. Possible values are OR and AND.

```
'tax_query' => array(

'relation' => 'OR',

array(

'taxonomy' => 'products-category',

'field' => 'slug',

'terms' => $course_terms,

),

array(

'taxonomy' => 'space',

'field' => 'slug',

'terms' => $space_terms,

),

),
```

Taxonomy in WordPress is a way of grouping posts (native and custom posts types) together in easily manageable groups. For WordPress users, the popular taxonomy options are Categories and Tags. In many cases, you might need to create custom taxonomies in WordPress websites to better organize your content.

For further detail, please have a look:

Search on 'tax_query' in this official article
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Helpful examples and further explanation
https://generatewp.com/retrieving-results-filtered-wp_tax_query/

WordPress Custom Taxonomy: Create & Display Custom Taxonomy In WordPress
https://www.wpblog.com/create-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress/